# Any way to map transportation layer protocol name with number？

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, tcp

The Internet protocol on transportation layer like tcp/udp/icmp should have a unique number to identify them. Like tcp is 6， icmp is 1. Like the wiki said

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers

Is there any model or  package can help use to map the protocol name and number?

For example :

```
import the_model

# below code should return 6
the_model.func('tcp')
```

can you tell me some package that can do the same thing like above "the_model"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for [`socket.getprotobyname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getprotobyname).

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getprotobyname('tcp')
6
>>> socket.getprotobyname('udp')
17
>>> socket.getprotobyname('icmp')
1
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks very much:)